# Return iterable with Resolve in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise, nightmare

I would like to return not only the result of this Promise but also the iterable, the `url`, with which it was a called. `urls` is an array of urls.

```
function findMainLink(urls) {
  return Promise.all(urls.map((url) => {
  var result = nightmare
    .goto(url)
    .wait('#main')
    .evaluate(function() {
       return document.querySelector('#main a').href;
    });

    nightmare.end()
    return result
  }
}

vo(findMainLink)([
 'https://yahoo.com',
 'https://google.com'
])
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

when I do `return {result,url}` it does not resolve but instead gives me back the current status of the promise. How would I include the url in the result?

Comment: I am handling promises from the npm package nightmare and I want to visit websites at the same time, hence the promises. I want to include the url with which the nightmare function is called

Comment: And that has...what exactly to do with the code you posted?

Comment: You really should show us your actual code, not some simplified example that barely matches it.

Comment: @torazaburo Calling `Promise.all()` on an array of non-promises is actually possible. It behaves like calling it on an array of promises, except that it resolves without delay.

Comment: I have updated the example to include my code. I don't understand why I am showered by downvotes :(

Comment: `return {result,url}` provide an example with the output.

Comment: so I cannot return an object from a Promise but an array?

Comment: You can, it should work. note however that if `result` is a promise, then you're no longer returning a promise and instead are returning an object that has a promise and your .then will run before any of them resolve.. You returned an object, not a promise, and therefore it's giving you an object, not the result of the promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
function findMainLink(urls) {
  return Promise.all(urls.map((url) => {
    var result = nightmare
      .goto(url)
      .wait('#main')
      .evaluate(function() {
         return document.querySelector('#main a').href;
      });

    nightmare.end();
    return result;
  })
    .then(results => results.map((result, i) => ({result, url[i]}));
}
```

Passing an array of tuples to `Promise.all` of course won't work, since a tuple is not a promise and `Promise.all` has no way to know it's supposed to look inside the `tuple`. Instead, the code above waits for all the promises to resolve then maps the results to give you your array of tuples (and returns a promise for that).

Comment: hmm, yeah that would work. I was thinking doing `return result.then( result => {result, url} )` but both would have the same result.

Comment: Either is OK, yours might be a little bit cleaner. Minor syntax note, needs to be `result => ({result, url})`.